# Session is destroyed after return from paypal

Tags: php, session, paypal

I have integrated the paypal recurring subscription with my site.I have set return url after the successful transaction..But once I redirected from paypal I got my session values are destroyed and it returns nothing on that page as well..I could not get the response(transaction id,status, etc)..Any one can instruct me to get this resolved.

Comment: What errors show up in your log files? Have you tried using `var_dump()` or `error_log()` anywhere to log the progression of the values? Are you sure the session is saving to begin with? What have you tried? What code are you using?

Comment: The session/login/logout is working well..But I got my session destroyed only I made the purchase and redirected from the paypal..also on return page I did get the response from paypal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that your response is coming back to the correct URL.
On some servers, www.site.com is considered different (session-wise) from site.com

Answer (score 2):

With PayPal you have to set up something separate to listen out for an HTTP request from PayPal - the data you need doesn't get returned when PayPal send the customer back to the return URL. You have to set a notify URL, which is entirely separate from the return URL.

I recently used PayPal with the CodeIgniter framework and I set up a controller that is dedicated to listening out for PayPal. In the submission form, I defined a parameter for the form that contains the customer's ID as well as some other details needed, and PayPal include this when they make an HTTP request to the notify URL I specified. Then, when my controller that listens out for PayPal receives a request, it sends it back to PayPal via POST to acknowledge it to them.

The PayPal documentation isn't that great IMHO, especially when it comes to recurring subscriptions.

Comment: can you please provide a demo code as i am facing same situation in my CI with recurring

Comment: @jilesh I don't use CodeIgniter any more and haven't used PayPal in years. You should be able to figure out how to do this using the documentation for PayPal and CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and solved it by commenting this line

```
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
```

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

PayPal does not cause the issue, it is the **return URL** that you set upon successful transaction **or** you just accidentally destroy the session

### In PHP:

If you were to set your URL as **[absolute path](https://www.contentkingapp.com/academy/urls/faq/absolute-vs-relative)** it will cause an issue:
`define("SUCCESS_URL", "http://localhost/vendor/paypal_payment_success.php");`

### Why

1. Because when you deploy your website, your domain is unlikely to be
   `http://localhost`, it will probably look like `www.example.com`.
2. Redirecting to a new domain/subdomain will initiate a new session

   - if you are intended to redirect to a new domain/subdomain, use `ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', '0');` before starting the session, to maintain the same session ID

### Solution

So, to solve this issue, you should only set the **return URL** as **relative path** like this:
`define("SUCCESS_URL", "/vendor/paypal_payment_success.php");`

You're welcome.